# Show SplashScreen for Android and iOS, but not the web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, splash-screen

I am using the [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) plugin to show a splash screen for my flutter application. I need to show the splash screen for Android and iOS, but not for the web app. How can I disable the splash screen for the web app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set

```yaml
web: false
```

in your config.

Edit: note that you can avoid using a splash screen on web, but the browser will display a white screen while the Flutter framework loads, so without a splash screen, your users will experience a blank screen for some period of time depend on the speed of their connection.

Comment: Doesnt work for me.

Comment: Have you already created the splash screen for web and now you want to disable it?

Answer (score -1):

You can check what platform you're on kIsWeb:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (!kIsWeb) {
    //Dont show splash
}else{
    //Show splash
}
```

Comment: While using the plugin that has been mentioned, the splash screen is rendered without any call made from the code.